# How to implement a trait when an associated type includes a closure?

Tags: rust, types

I would like to implement `IntoIterator` using a map over an iterator, like this:

```rust
struct MyStruct {
    txt: String,
}

impl IntoIterator for MyStruct {
    type Item = String;
    type IntoIter = std::iter::Map<std::ops::Range<char>, WhatAmISupposedToWriteHere>;

    fn into_iter(self) -> Self::IntoIter {
        ('a'..'z').into_iter().map(move |c| {
            let mut t = self.txt.clone();
            t.push(c);
            t
        })
    }
}
```

What is the type of my `|c| self.txt.clone().push(c)` closure that I'd have to write into the `IntoIter` type?

- The IDE says the type is `[closure@src/example.rs:16:36: 16:64]` which isn't very useful.
- I tried `dyn Fn(char) -> String` but then the compiler complains that `IntoIter` doesn't have a size known at compile-time.
- I also tried just writing `_` instead of a specific type, but an `_` is not allowed in a type signature - although it looks like the compiler can definitely find out the type on its own, so it would be nice if it would just magically define `IntoIter` for me.

What is the correct way of using `map` when implementing `IntoIterator`?

Comment: [The duplicate applied to your situation](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a939f8065c362e0921fc4e8601b16660)

Comment: Not directly relevant, but you probably meant an inclusive range: `'a'..='z'`.